# Is there a way to the run the Python 3.2 interpreter inside Emacs 24?

Tags: macos, emacs, python

I'm using a nightly build of Emacs.app 24 from [Emacs For OS X](http://emacsforosx.com/builds) on OS X 10.7. After loading in my `foo.py` script everything works fine, except when I click `"Start interpreter"` from the menu bar Emacs starts the default 2.7 interpreter and fails to run my scripts written in Python 3.2. Is there any way to customize it, so that it starts the 3.2 interpreter?

I've tried `(setq py-python-command "python3")` in my `.emacs`, but it still starts the default 2.7.

Comment: Have you tried using a fully qualified path to your python interpreter?

Comment: yes; doesn't help. I can do `M-x shell` then `python3.2`, but evaluating scripts in `python-mode` always brings up the 2.7 interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

M-x python3

should do it.

if not, please get latest source:

https://launchpad.net/python-mode/+download

if still not working, please file a bug report at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the posts here on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501626/both-python-2-and-3-in-emacs) It looks like someone had a similar problem (though they wanted to be able to switch between interpreters.)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the variable

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")
```

<kbd>C-h v python-shell-interpreter</kbd> says

> Documentation: Default Python interpreter for shell.